# Ask about same software like putty

Tags: 11.10, software-center, remote-desktop, putty

I want to share document in remote computer.

Through which software can be supposed same like `putty` in `UBUNTU 11.10`?

Comment: @Dhaiwat budh--Please Clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putty` itself is based on SSH, which should be installed on your 11.10. At a shell type:

```
ssh username@hostname
```

The machine you're connecting to will need to have an SSH server running. You can set one up quite simply using the following code:

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

To transfer files to and from a machine, you can use SFTP (implemented as `psftp` in the `putty` suite) or FTP, but both SSH and SFTP/FTP operate more on a client-server model (one machine serving, many connecting)

As maythux points out, if you are looking for a file sharing solution (many serving, many connecting), have a look at SAMBA, NFS or the Nautilus sharing option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking For file sharing sofwtare and its probably SAMBA what you need.

check their [site](http://www.samba.org/)

see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html) also its about different sharing techniques in Ubuntu

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 Sharing option (nautilus sharing) is founded by default just a right click on the file/folder you want to share

From the other pc:

1- if windows host open Run and type the iddress of the remote pc containing the shared directory

2- if ubuntu host from the global menu file --> connect to server --> type the remote ip --> choose Windows share --> then connect

See [this](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/quickly-share-your-documents-folder-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) and [this](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/05/19/how-to-share-files-and-folders-in-ubuntu/) tutorials if you want more explanation